# Code optimization by reducing number of if else statement

Tags: python-3.x, optimization

I am writing code for library where thousand different color codes are stored and according to the normalized passed value the color will be selected. Here is the code for reference for just ten color to be returned :

```
colour_coding=[]
i=0
step=0
while i<1000:
    temp=(step,0,0)
    colour_coding.append(temp)
    step+=0.001
    i+=1

def color_code(value):
    if value>=0 and value<=0.1:
        return color_code[0]
    elif value>0.1 and value<=0.2:
        return color_code[1]
    elif value>0.2 and value<=0.3:
        return color_code[2]
    elif value>0.3 and value<=0.4:
        return color_code[3]
    elif value>0.4 and value<=0.5:
        return color_code[4]
    elif value>0.5 and value<=0.6:
        return color_code[5]
    elif value>0.6 and value<=0.7:
        return color_code[6]
    elif value>0.7 and value<=0.8:
        return color_code[7]
    elif value>0.8 and value<=0.9:
        return color_code[8]
    else:
        return color_code[9]
```

Now i want to have more precision for color for that i have to write around thousand if else which will be a tedious and repetition job, is there any way by which i can optimize this code ?

Answer (score 1):

Not a solution but this might give you an idea:

```
 import math
 def color_code(value):
    return color_code[math.ceil(value * 10) -1]
```

This code should be able to handle all of the conditions in your code above. You'll need to add condition to handle the index > 9 scenario.

For thousand iterations, you just need to find the right math function to calculate the right index based on the range.

Couple of caveats:

1. I'm not a python dev, so my syntax may be off.
2. Your if conditions probably don't need the greater than checks. The else if will guarantee that the first matched condition will automatically exclude all other conditions.

i.e. you should be able to get away with code like this:

```
def color_code(value):
    if value<=0.1:
       return color_code[0]
    elif value<=0.2:
       return color_code[1]
etc.
```